# Graphics Driver installation problem

Tags: apt, dpkg, fglrx

I have Ubuntu 14.04.02 installed on my computer. I wanted to install AMD graphics driver file `fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb` and i tried the command :

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb
```

but it was showing some dependency problems.Here it is what it was showing :

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx:
fglrx depends on fglrx-core; however: Package fglrx-core is not installed.
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index....
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:  fglrx
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: run 'sudo apt-get install fglrx-core'

Comment: Then rerun your install command

Comment: @Daniel i did as your suggestion but unfortunately it did not work and showed that fglrx-core was not installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install same driver a supported way.

First remove what you tried to install by

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Then install this driver from Ubuntu repositories

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

This will install 15.200 fglrx.